# unable to get the value of the text field with the help of respective checkboxes. please help

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

I've a doubt. I've 3 textboxes and each is having checkboxes next to it. I want to display 
the values of only those textboxes whose respective checkboxes are clicked. Following is the attached HTML and PHP codes:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>
            <form name="f" method="post" action="4.php">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <th> Facility </th> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="a1" value="a"></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="facility[]" name="facility[]" value="Hostel"></td>
                  </tr> 
                  <tr>  
                    <td><input type="text" name="b1" value="b"></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="facility[]" name="facility[]" value="Transport"></td>
                  </tr> 
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="c1" value="c"></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="facility[]" name="facility[]" value="Food"></td>
                  </tr> 
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>   
               </form>
          </body>
</html>
```

and below is the PHP part.

```
<?php
    $a=$_POST['a1'];
    $b=$_POST['b1'];
    $c=$_POST['c1'];

    $facilityArray = $_POST['facility'];
    $facility = "";
    if(count($facilityArray) > 0)
    {
        foreach($facilityArray as $fac)
        {
            $facility .= " " . $fac;
        }
    }

    echo $facility; echo "<br>"; 
    echo $a; echo "<br>";
    echo $b; echo "<br>";
    echo $c;
?>
```

With the help of following codes I am able to display all the values of checked checkboxes. I am also able to display the values of all the textboxes. But I actually want to display the values of only those textboxes whose respective checkboxes are clicked. I know it may be a very basic question but please help me grow in PHP. Thanks in advance... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textboxes should also be in an array post to achieve this.

To achieve this change the input lines as:

```
<td><input type="text" name="textboxes[]" value="a"></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="facility[]" name="facility[]"></td>
```

From php you'll be getting the posted textboxes in an array as:

```
$textbox=$_POST['textboxes'];
```

You should then loop through the checkboxes array and if the corresponding checkbox is "on" (clicked), then display the textboxes value. To do this you would also need a counter to make sure you are on the same array index for both checkboxes and textboxes:

```
 if(count($facilityArray) > 0)
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach($facilityArray as $fac)
    {
        if($fac == "on")
        {
            echo $textbox[$i] . "</br>";
        }
        $i ++;
    }
}
```

I've also added a name to your submit button so you only check the form when it is submitted.
Your page should now look something like this:

```
        <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $textbox=$_POST['textboxes'];
    
        $facilityArray = $_POST['facility'];
        
        if(count($facilityArray) > 0)
        {
            $i = 0;
            foreach($facilityArray as $fac)
            {
                if($fac == "on")
                {
                    echo $textbox[$i] . "</br>";
                }
                $i ++;
            }
        }
    
    }
    ?>
    <form name="f" method="post" action="4.php">
                
    
        <table>
                      <tr>
                        <th> Facility </th> 
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="textboxes[]" value="a"></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="facility[]" name="facility[]"></td>
                      </tr> 
                      <tr>  
                        <td><input type="text" name="textboxes[]" value="b"></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="facility[]" name="facility[]"></td>
                      </tr> 
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="textboxes[]" value="c"></td><td><input type="checkbox" id="facility[]" name="facility[]"></td>
                      </tr> 
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
                      </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

## UPDATE:

To make sure that the $_POST variable exists before assigning it to a variable we use the isset(). In your case just update the php segment as:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['textboxes']))
        {
            $textbox=$_POST['textboxes'];
            
            if(isset($_POST['facility']))
            {
                $facilityArray = $_POST['facility'];
                
                if(count($facilityArray) > 0)
                {
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach($facilityArray as $fac)
                    {
                        if($fac == "on")
                        {
                            echo $textbox[$i] . "</br>";
                        }
                        $i ++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
?>
```

Where the only changes are the addition of another two if statements that take a boolean flag from the isset() function according to whether the $_POST variable has been posted successfully

```
if(isset($_POST['textboxes']))
```

AND

```
if(isset($_POST['facility']))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a very quick reply and sorry for the late response from my side.Your's code is working perfectly and my intention is achieved except one and that is when I do not check the checkbox and submit the form;that time it throws following error. Notice: Undefined index: textboxes in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Test\HRMS\try\chcking with checkboxes\2.php on line 53
Notice: Undefined index: myCheckBox in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Test\HRMS\try\chcking with checkboxes\2.php on line 55.I am still new to PHP coding. Hope you will solve this problem in a moment.Thanks :(

Comment: These are the two lines where it shows an errors when I submit my form without checking any checkboxes. If I check any 1 checkbox then it works fine. $textbox=$_POST['textboxes'];
$facilityArray = $_POST['facility'];

Comment: Thanks  Kypros... You made my day. But it shows one thing that I still have to improve a lot if I want to proceed in PHP. Thank once again... :)